# Why does expectPUT/POST/etc represent request bodies as a string?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, httpbackend, angular-mock

Look at the API for `$httpbackend`, we can see that functions like `expectPut` can take up to 4 parameters. The second parameter can be a function which takes 1 parameter: a string.  This string represents the body of the HTTP request.

But why is it a string? Wouldn't it make more sense for it to be JSON? Is there a technical reason why Angular needs to give me the body back as a string instead of JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP request bodies *are* strings, it doesn't really make sense to represent them in any other way.

In this instance you may be passing an object to the function, but in a real webrequest it won't make it to the server as an object, it will be a string representation of the object.  Equally, it could be any other string - there's no way angular could parse and pass any given string as an object to the callback.

There's nothing stopping you from serialising your request as a string (or letting angular do it internally), then parsing it as JSON within the callback function if that's what you're expecting.